# Variable Id Called in JS Function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I've spent the past couple hours googling and browsing W3Schools and couldn't find a way to do exactly what I wanted. I've found similar articles but they don't answer my question perfectly.

So what I'm trying to do is this, create a JS function that when called in HTML will take the information given to return the appropriate information. E.G, I want there to be two HTML buttons. If the user presses the first button, it calls the function "onclick='show(x, y)'" and x and y which stand for another paragraph and an image. If the user presses the second button, it calls the same function with different variables "onclick='show(x, z)'" which would display the same paragraph as the other button would but would display a different image.

Basically, is it possible for HTML elements to have IDs that can be variable in JS so I that I do not have to create an individual JS function for every single button?

My Javascript:

```
<script>
 var Show = function(elID, elID2) {
 var el1 = document.getElementByID(elID);
 var el2 = document.getElementByID(elID2);
 var both = (elID) + " " + (elID2);
 document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML = both;
}
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<p id="demo">
 <button onclick="Show(77, demo)">Click to convert</button>
</p>
```

I am still learning the ins and outs of Javascript so any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

yes, enclose the arguments in quotes

```
<button onclick="Show('77', 'demo')">Click to convert</button>
```

without quotes `77` will be passed correctly but demo will not be since it will look for a `demo` property in `window` scope.

Answer (score 0):

> You should get `innerHTML` before inserting. Also note that, you must pass `id` attributes wrapped in `quotes(')`.

*ID attributes should at least have one character and it should not start with NUMBER*

```js
function Show(elID, elID2) {
  var el1 = document.getElementByID(elID).innerHTML;
  var el2 = document.getElementByID(elID2).innerHTML;
  var both = (elID) + " " + (elID2);
  document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML = both;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  <button onclick="Show('77', 'demo')">Click to convert</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could lay aside the inline JavaScript and opt for a different way, separating your markup from your logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/tricon/p2esv818/

HTML:

```
<button id="button" data-parameter-one='{ "keyOne": "valueOne", "keyTwo": "valueTwo" }'>
    Some button
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var parameters = this.getAttribute("data-parameter-one");
  parameters = JSON.parse(parameters);
  console.log(parameters);
});
```